# Hibernate generator class increment vs sequence?

Tags: hibernate

I can see many generator classes at http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernateidgeneratorelement.shtml
for generating identifier. (Official list is here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e5294)

But if I look at `increment` and `sequence`, they sound the same, I am not sure what the difference is and which is better?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Sequence` uses the database sequence (eg in Oracle) to generate the id whereas `increment` keeps track of id in jvm and increments it within process. Sequence is safer if any other program/person is going to insert into the database table.

To use sequence :

1. your database must support sequences (Oracle, DB2, Postgresql...)
2. you should create a sequence (`CREATE SEQUENCE mySquence;`)

`Increment` is less safer solution (but portable, to those db that don't support Sequence) and good for testing and\or getting started. There are better ways (eg native/identity etc) than using `Increment` for use in production.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the auto generated value. Hibernate will then produce the best strategy for the DB you're using.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

Also means you can test against a simple in memory DB like HsqlDB without changing your entities.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score -1):

You can try this lines

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
```

Comment: Please add further explanation to this answer