# Error during primary key generation with SPRING JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Hi all i have a weird problem with the generation of PK calling the jpa method save.

Here and exmpale of the snippet i have implemented:

Entity

```
@Table(name = "MYTABLE")
@Entity
public class EEMYTABLE{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "IDMYTABLE")
    @GenericGenerator(name="generator" , strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
    private Long id;
    ...
```

Repository

```
public interface MyTableRepository JpaRepository<MYTABLE,Long> {}
```

Service

```
@Autowired
private MyTableRepository myTableRepository;


public void saveNewRecord() {
        EEMYTABLE newRecord = new EEMYTABLE();
        myTableRepository.save(newRecord);
```

Problem Steps:

- i run save method from my local server. It's all ok.
- i run the ssave method from my remote server. It fires the following excepion: " ORA-00001: unique constraint violated "
- now if i run again the method from the server is all ok.
- if i follow with another call from my local env i have the exception: " ORA-00001: unique constraint violated "

It seems that if i run the method in more than 1 env there is a desync in the internal spring generator value.

Someone with ideas to fix it?

I try some solutions read on internet but i ave not solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "increment" hibernate strategy is not suitable if you have several environments using the same database since it relies on incrementation of an integer inside the JVM.
This explains why your environments generate the same ids.

In your case, you have to rely on a database mechanism, e.g. sequences.

See [Hibernate generator class increment vs sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475743/hibernate-generator-class-increment-vs-sequence) for more details.